# Google Mobile Vision library delays or fails on download

Tags: android, google-vision

On my app I use Google Mobile Vision in order to recognize faces.
I use gms play library and it works fine on most devices :

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
```

Here to note that I've tried also updated versions of gms vision like 15.0.0.

Recently I received many bad reviews and some users complained that app couldn't recognize their face.

So I found some devices that had this issue and it seems that problem is Google Play Services delay a lot(or just fail) to download GMS vision even if device has much free storage.

Android Studio log says :

```
I/Vision: Loading library libmobile_vision_face.so
I/Vision: libmobile_vision_face.so library load status: false
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:1702
I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 1702
```

So it's going like this : The first attempts for using my app failing since GMS Vision hasn't been downloaded or working. But after some hours on most of the cases it seems that is working fine.

For understanding better why this happening I tried when app began to work well to **clear Data of Google Play Services** of device.  It stopped working for a while and then after some hours its OK again without any user action.

So it seems that is a matter of Google Services.

Practically many devices would have problem using my app since they are very new enabled or user has recently wipe data etc or for any other random reason.

Can I do anything for that?